# JQuery Script, Works in Firefox, not in IE, Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which slides a container down and another up, and vice versa depending on the condition of closed/enabled variables.

The script works fine in firefox, however in IE and Chrome, it just doesnt work :(

Can anyone please advise?

Many thanks! heres the script.

(The OCH var takes the height of a continer which elements are loaded into via ajax, so it then knows when to open it again how many px to open to - is this the best way?)

```
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                //Grab the height of the container after its loaded with all the calls in...
                var och = $('#calls').height();
                //Are we allowed to close this panel yet?
                var enabled = false;
                //is the panel closed or not?
                var closed = false;
                $(".survey-description").click(function () {
                    if (enabled == true) {
                        if (closed == false) {
                            $(this).closest("#calls").stop().animate({"height": "44px"}, "fast");
                            closed = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).closest("#calls").stop().animate({"height": och}, "medium");
                            closed = false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                $(".linktoCall").click(function () {
                    if (closed == false) {
                        //Now we can toggle the top panel...
                        enabled = true;
                        $(this).closest("#calls").stop().animate({"height": "44px"}, "fast");
                        closed = true;
                    }
                });

            });
```

EDIT here is some html of the rendered elements.

```
<div id="survey-description"></div>
<div id="calls">
    <div>
        <p onclick="showCall('tgkn5xabgnivkaf');" id="notstarted" class="linktoCall">59677 tgkn5xabgnivkaf<br>NOT STARTED - SAVED</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="aCall">
</div>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a great description of a problem - you need to be more specific about *what* is and isn't working.  Are you getting any error messages in the developer console?

Comment: It doesnt slide up and down? That is how it doesnt work. It remains static. Error I get in chrome dev tools is

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: Where is the element with class `survey-description`?

Comment: Re-editied. its just a div button above all others.

Comment: Well, if that's the html, then `$(".survey-description").closest("#calls")` will not match anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the HTML snippet I guess it should be

```
<div class="survey-description"></div>
```

because the selector `$('.survey-description')` refers to a class, not an id.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a quick guess as I don't know the html structure in question and don't have time to check the rest, but if there are conflicting element ids (such as two elements with the id "calls") different browsers will behave differently. So check do a check for this to make sure that is not the problem.

(Also, use === in comparisons instead of ==)

Answer (score 1):

it might not work if your html code is not valid... and I bet you didn't close a div or something...

You can check here your page: http://validator.w3.org/

Please also remove just for test the "px" value from

```
animate({"height": "xxpx"} ...
```

and let it

```
animate({"height": 25}...
```

Comment: Removed the px and the ""'s works in FF perfectly, however still the same in Chrome/IE. :(